# Not able to achieve concurrency with swift in React native app

Tags: swift, react-native

Im trying to achieve encryption tasks running parallelly in native.

**My implementation is as below:**

**It is each time JS call native, the task will be wrapped into `queue.async`:-**

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "decrypting")

@objc(decrypt:withKey:iv:tag:withResolver:withRejecter:)

func decrypt(hexCipherText: String, key: String, iv: String, tag: String, resolve:@escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject:@escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    queue.async {
        do {
            guard let keyData = Data(hexString: key) else {
                throw CryptoError.runtimeError("Invalid key")
            }

            let decryptedData = try self.decryptData(cipherData: hexCipherText.hexaData, key: keyData, iv: iv, tag: tag)
            resolve(decryptedData.hexadecimal)
        } catch CryptoError.runtimeError(let errorMessage) {
            reject("InvalidArgumentError", errorMessage, nil)
        } catch {
            reject("DecryptionError", "Failed to decrypt", error)
        }
    }
}
```

However when running at the same time of multiple JS calls to native encryption, it does not work as expected, my performance is still slow like before.

```
for (const data of encryptedArr) {
   await JSCallNativeEncryption(data);
}
```

or without await:

```
for (const data of encryptedArr) {
   JSCallNativeEncryption(data)
      .then(a => console.log(a))
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a `DispatchQueue` is serial.

See documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300059-init

> The attributes to associate with the queue. Include the concurrent attribute to create a dispatch queue that executes tasks concurrently. If you omit that attribute, the dispatch queue executes tasks serially.

Instantiate your queue with the `.concurrent` attribute:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "decrypting", attributes: .concurrent)
```

You also need to update your loop.

`await` will wait for a result before continuing, effectively making your calls serial.

If using promise syntax, you need to keep a reference to the `JSCallNativeEncryption` call, otherwise the object will get deallocated on the next iteration of the loop.

So something like this:

```
const unresolvedPromises = encryptedArr.map(data => JSCallNativeEncryption(data));
const results = await Promise.all(unresolvedPromises);
```